# Click Propagating after Prevent Default

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use jQuery on a nav menu.  When the url is "#", it will scroll to the anchor.  When it is not on the home page, it will add the # and anchor details and do a redirect.  I'm trying to catch a specific nav item, "Contact", and am catching it fine, however when I process it it is as if Contact was clicked twice in a row.

So for instance in the following code, I get the alert "Woo!" twice in a row and the slide toggle opens and closes the target div instead of either opening or closing based on state.

```
$('#menu-home li a').click(function(event) {
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  if (target == 'http://#') {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var scrlto = $(this).attr('title');
    if (window.location.href == homeurl) {

      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + scrlto + "-anchor").offset().top - 90
      }, 500, function() {
        if (scrlto == "Contact") {
          $('.contactform').slideToggle(400);
        }
      });


    } else {
      window.location.href = homeurl + '#' + scrlto + "-anchor";
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Without even looking at your actual question/code...do you know there's a different between default behavior and event propagation?

Comment: *" I get the alert "Woo!" twice in a row"* - You seem to have removed this from your question in a previous edit :)

Comment: You maybe are binding the event twice... If this js comes from an external js file check that you are including it just once. if its a local file check that the selector for click has a length of 1. Just ideas out of past personal experiences

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to stop propagating, use `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Where would this go?  I tried in the place of the fiest event.preventDefault() and the links are followed.  If I put it within the check for "Contact" I get the same behaviour with the div opening and then immediately closing.

Comment: Yea you have to use both to define both behaviors. `.click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Updated the code in my question.      if (scrlto == "Contact") {
        $('.contactform').slideToggle(400);
    } still fires twice.